# Why is my list not rendering on the page using sort ()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I have this project in react where I  need to sort my data in desc and asc. My new list is not being rendered on the page. Here is just a snippet of the code.

```
const list = [
    {
      Id: "1",
      Time: "2022-01-18T14:52:48Z",
    },
    {
     Id: "3",
     Time: "2022-01-18T15:05:28Z",
    },
    {
      Id: "2",
      Time: "2022-01-18T16:57:58Z",
    },
    {
      Id: "0",
      Time: "2022-01-18T16:00:28Z",
    },
  ];

  list.sort((firstItem, secondItem) => firstItem.Id - secondItem.Id);
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using to render the list to the page?

Comment: This sort works well enough for you, right?  What did you do with `list` after this?

Comment: Why are you subtracting secondItem from firstItem... use a comparison operator 
`.sort((a, b) => (a.Id > b.Id ? -1 : 1))`

Comment: @KeatonBenning that's not exactly a lot clearer. Plus his `sort` function works. He could also compare via a `localeCompare` but it would be the same result.

Comment: What happens if you change the Id's from strings to Int's

Answer (score 0):

```
     ASC :  list.sort(function(a, b) {
           return a.Id - b.Id;
         });


    DESC:  list.sort(function(a, b) {
           return b.Id - a.Id;
         });
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot , and how to call it in a button on click so I can render it on my page ? <button onClick = {name of the function}></button> . Sorry I am new in react ...